# Do tensors $n_in_jn_kn_l$ where $n_i$ is a vector span all 4th-order symmetric tensors?

Tags: geometry, tensor-products, tensor-decomposition

A real tensor $T$ of order $r$ in dimension $n$ is a collection of real coefficients $T_{i_1i_2\dots i_r}$, $1\leq i_1, i_2, \dots, i_r\leq n$. A tensor $T$ is symmetric if the coefficients $T_{i_1i_2\dots i_r}$ are invariant under permutation of indices.

**Do tensors of the form $n_in_jn_kn_l$ span all 4th order symmetric tensors?**

This question came up when I was studying the elastic behavior of Bravais lattices. I believe the answer to be negative in 3D because some symmetric 4th order tensors are isotropic and I don't see how a (finite) sum of $n_in_jn_kn_l$ can be isotropic. I am mostly interested in this case (4th order tensors in 3D). But I wouldn't mind learning about other dimensions (say 2D) or orders.

By the way, this is true for 2nd order tensors in any dimension: matrices $n_in_j$ span all symmetric matrices because they are diagonalizable. For symmetric 4th order tensors, diagonalizability ensures that they are spanned by $m_{ij}m_{kl}$ but I don't see how to further break these into a sum of $n_in_jn_kn_l$, or if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Tensors of the form $n_in_jn_kn_l$ (tensor products of four vectors, also known as rank-1 tensors) can produce all fully symmetric tensors by linear combination, but they are not fully symmetric themselves. However, the symmetrizations of $n_in_jn_kn_l$ *do* span all fully symmetric tensors while being symmetric themselves. Note that linear combination is necessary, as not every fully symmetric tensor is the symmetrization of a rank-1 tensor.

Comment: Pardon my shady notations: $n$ is the vector, $n_i$ are the components. So $n_in_jn_kn_l$ is symmetric.

Comment: Then I don't get it. A tensor needs four input vectors, but n is only one of them? Or are you trying to specify the tensor by only saying what happens if you input the same vector four times?

Comment: The tensor is the set of its coefficients in a canonical basis. See edited question.

Comment: I still don't understand your notation. Could you provide a concrete example of a vector $n$ and the resulting coefficients $T_{i_1 \ldots i_r}$?

Comment: Say $n_1 = 1$ and $n_i=0$ for $i \neq 1$. Then, $n_1n_1n_1n_1=1$ and all other $n_in_jn_kn_l$ are zero.

Comment: oh so you're defining $T_{ijkl} := n_in_jn_kn_l$, got it.